# SVG animations - how to keep text horizontal while its parent rotates around a center point

Tags: svg, text, rotation, transform, transformation

I have the following animation:

[image]

I want the circle containing the `ETH / USD` animation to rotate around the centerpoint of all these circles, but the text itself I want to stay perfectly horizontal. How do I do this?

If it helps, I'm using the svg.js library (https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotate the circle counterclockwise around its own center whiile it is rotating clockwise around the main center.

Let `group` be a group containing the small circle with radius `r` and the text. Let them be centered on (0,0). Let `(cx, cy)` be the central rotation point. Loop endlessly with even pace in a full circle taking 15s:

```
var group = draw.group();
group.circle(r, 0, 0);
group.text('ETH / USD');

group.animate(15000, '-').rotate(-360).loop()
     .animate(15000, '-').rotate(360, cx, cy).loop();
```